# Insert multiple rows using a subquery

Tags: sql-server

My scenario:

- I dynamically spawn new databases in certain circumstances.
- Each new database will have the same base tables created dynamically
  when the database is created

I need to validate the users in each database that has a table called "Users" in it, so I'm trying to insert data into a separate global table from each database's "User" table, like so:

```
DECLARE @ROWNUM INT = 1
,@DBName VARCHAR(100) = '';

WHILE @DBName IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @DBName = (SELECT [name] FROM (SELECT [name], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [name]) AS ROWNUM 
        FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id NOT IN(1, 2, 3, 4)) AS DBs WHERE ROWNUM = @ROWNUM);

    IF @DBName != '' AND @DBName IS NOT NULL
        EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName + '];

            DECLARE @EmailAddress VARCHAR(150)

            IF OBJECT_ID(''[' + @DBName + '].[dbo].[Users]'') IS NOT NULL
            SET @EmailAddress = (SELECT EmailAddress FROM ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Users]);

            INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[UserValidation]
            (
                DB
                ,EmailAddress
            )

            SELECT ''' + @DBName + ''', @EmailAddress
            --SELECT ''' + @DBName + ''', @EmailAddress FROM ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Users]

        ');
    SET @ROWNUM += 1;
END;
```

I know the issue is coming from this subquery:`SET @EmailAddress = (SELECT EmailAddress FROM ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Users]);`

I'm just not sure how to insert the multiple values generated by the subquery into the `[SomeDB].[dbo].[UserValidation]` object.

Using the `WHERE` clause didn't help because there's 1 `DBName` and multiple `EmailAddresses`.  I've even tried doing this with a `VALUES` block but that didn't work either.

I'm really hoping the solution isn't resorting to a nested `CURSOR`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @EmailAddress is VARCHAR(150), you can either use `SET @EmailAddress = (SELECT TOP 1 EmailAddress FROM ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Users]);` or declare @EmailAddress as table and then iterate over the list of emails to inset them

Comment: _Any suggestions?_ Use the [`model` database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database)?

Comment: If you want to `INSERT` all the users into a single table, what's wrong with `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (EmailAddress) SELECT EmailAddress FROM DB1.dbo.YourTable UNION ALL SELECT EmailAddress FROM DB2.dbo.YourTable...`?

Comment: Side note, things like `'[' + @DBName + ']'` and `'''' + @DBName + ''''` aren't safe from injection. Even though you are getting the value from system tables, you should still be quoting the values properly with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: @Larnu The script needs to be dynamic, which means I'm going to have to run a ```cursor``` over it to satisfy your suggestion, which I'd ideally want to avoid. That's why I used a ```WHILE``` loop instead. I don't want to go back and maintain this script every time a new database is spawned

Comment: Why why can't use use `model` as @AlwaysLearning suggested? Then the objects are always there. If you're always trying to `INSERT` the data into a "master" table every time a database is created, then you have a design flaw by the sounds of it.

Comment: It's by design. Using the model database as a template won't work in this case because I won't be managing the data in each of the databases. There are objects that are custom to each individual database after they're created.
Edit: Inserting the the data into a "master" table is a temporary solution until I've figured out how to make it more elegant

Comment: If it's temporary, then using a `UNION` seems like a "good" interim solution to me, until you fix the design. There's no need for a `CURSOR` when you're just writing a bunch of `UNION` statements.

Comment: I've actually tried a solution with ```UNION``` statements that are pushed through a ```CURSOR```. Only problem with that is: I can't use ```IF``` statements in a ```UNION``` :(
Resorting to a ```WHERE``` clause to mitigate this is a bit cumbersome to check if an object exists or not

Comment: Why are you hung up on using a `CURSOR` here? What's wrong with writing your own `UNION` statements? As you said, this is an interim solution, so just write the statement out yourself, and you have it till you fix the underlying problems. No need for a `CURSOR` or `WHILE`.

Comment: Because I have to iterate over all the databases in the instance, look for tables in each database and perform validations on certain objects if they exist. And I have to do it dynamically, with little to no maintenance

Comment: So this *isn't* just related to the `EmailAddress` column in the `Users` table in each database? Seems like we only, therefore, an but a small slice of the pie here. You need to explain the full problem in the question.

Comment: I did. I said:  "there's 1 DBName and multiple EmailAddresses". Those are the only 2 fields I want to store in this case. I didn't leave anything out

Comment: So what does *"and perform validations on certain objects if they exist"* have to do with this? What objects do you need to validate? That isn't covered in your question, you only talk about the data in specific columns, nothing about objects.

Comment: That's irrelevant for this discussion. If I can perform validation on 1 thing, I can reuse the solution on other things. For this discussion, there's no other calls to any other objects

Comment: Again, I feel like you're not telling us the full story here. If validating the objects isn't relevant, then why bring it up? If the validation of the objects if the thing you think you need a `CURSOR` for, but that isn't relevant, then we're back to what I said at the start; use a `UNION`. Again, it would simply be `SELECT EmailAddress from DB1.dbo.Users UNION ALL SELECT EmailAddress FROM DB2.dbo.Users UNION ALL.... UNION ALL SELECT EmailAddress FROM DB23.dbo.Users;`. Simple. I feel like you've overly complicating this as you *think* you need dynamic SQL when you likely don't.

Comment: If it's simply for ease of writing the query, get all the database names out of `sys.databases`, dump them into Excel (or your preferred Spreadsheet application) and use that to create the full statement with some simple string concatenation.

Comment: I think we're missing each other somewhere mate. Thanks for the suggestions :)
I'll go figure something out

Comment: If you take the time to [edit] your question to explain *why* this needs a Dynamic Solution, I'll be more than happy to help, but otherwise, like i mentioned, just use a `UNION ALL`, for your interim solution until you fix the design.